# Trigger Properties in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, intellisense

I am beginning to learn XAML and I am following along with the MCTS Self-Paced Training book. I've come to the section about triggers (more specifically Property Triggers) and I stumbled upon something that is rather annoying.

Here is my code:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property=""
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Now, when I want to get the property that Trigger points to I want Intellisense to list all the available properties and it doesn't. Is that something I'm doing, a problem with VS, or is it just not supported in that scenario. Besides this, it works when I set the Setter for the Trigger. For example:

`<Setter Property="INTELLISENSE WORKS" Value="Something" />`

I'd really like for the properties of the Button to show up like `IsMouseOver`.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion, as well as others, that Intellisense is not supported for Triggers.

Comment: I still don't get any options for trigger properties in VS 2013. I have no idea what options are available, which makes using Triggers difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of visual studio and upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 that everything should work as expected (Y).
Visual Studio 2010 (without the service pack) does not have intellisense for triggers.

Comment: I have VS2010 Ultimate and the SP1 is installed. I am going to try re-applying it though.

Comment: Have you tried to reset visual studio settings? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I did. I didn't do it from the command line but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Does it work in your code? I was reading up on the SP1 updates and I feel like it only applies to styles. Then again, I have been wrong many times before.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The intellisense only works on setters and not in triggers. I just tested here.

Comment: Damn! Well hopefully that is something they will integrate in the future. I don't see why they didn't do that in the first place because I can't see it being hard. I've downloaded multiple extensions and none seem to provide the Intellisense either. Oh well. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: You're welcome. You can try the "Resharper" that's a great helper of visual studio, but also do not know if it would work. Maybe in the future in visual studio 2012 work .. xD